# How to check startmenu exists in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have created shortcut menu folder using following code.In my script contains repair option.
If the user install second times repair option works fine.The second time user select shortcut menu different from existing one.In this situation there is two shortcut menu directory created.

```
 CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuFolder"
 CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuFolder\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
```

So if the user install second time need to check shortcut menu exist or not?

How to check already shortcut menu exist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question or what this repair function is but you can check if a file/folder exists with `IfFileExists`.

I suspect that the real issue is that the $StartMenuFolder variable is not restored when you run setup again. If you are using the MUI it has macros that helps you do this, if not you need to write $StartMenuFolder to the registry or a .ini file during install and try to restore it in .onInit...